# Error binding indices to device context [ STATE_SETTING ERROR #241: IASETINDEXBUFFER_INVALIDBUFFER]

Tags: directx, directx11, c++

This is how i initialized the D3D11_BUFFER_DESC for my indices. When i go to bound it to the deviceContext i get this error.

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer: The Buffer trying to be bound as an IndexBuffer did not have the appropriate bind flag set at creation time to allow the Buffer to be bound as an IndexBuffer. [ STATE_SETTING ERROR #241: IASETINDEXBUFFER_INVALIDBUFFER]

And is kinda of strange becouse i setted the bindFlags to "D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER"

```
   D3D11_BUFFER_DESC buffDescIndices;

    ZeroMemory(&buffDescIndices, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    buffDescIndices.MiscFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    buffDescIndices.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    buffDescIndices.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT) * ARRAYSIZE(indices);
    buffDescIndices.StructureByteStride = 0;
    buffDescIndices.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subResData2;
    subResData2.pSysMem = indices;
    HRESULT hr=device->CreateBuffer(&buffDescIndices, &subResData2, &mBoxIB);
```

And this is the deviceContext call

```
    deviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(mBoxIB, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes i am totally the stupidest person on this planet i setted

```
bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
```

Instead of

```
 buffDescIndices.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
```

...

Comment: The Debug device usually provides excellent hints for silly mistakes like that.